# python function use multiple defaults or no defaults at all

Tags: python, function, default

I am defining a class that represents a vector:

```
'''
An entity with size and direction
'''
UNINITIALIZED = -1

class myVector():    
    def __init__(self,direction = UNINITIALIZED,size = UNINITIALIZED):
        self.direction = direction
        self.size = size
```

For using the class I imagine 2 scenarios : Either I know the vector's charecharistics on initiation and then initiate it with these values:

```
v = myVector(4,2)
```

Or I do not know these on intiation and then I'm happy it will get the default values.

However, with the above implementation a third scenario is realized - initiating a vector using only 
the first argument :

```
v = myVector(4)
```

In this case only the second parameter (*size*) would be assigned the default value and the resulting object would not make much sense.

As I see it, **the desired behavior** in this case is either use both parameters or none. One way to implement this would be to raise an exception if this is the case.

```
def __init__(self,direction = UNINITIALIZED,size = UNINITIALIZED):
    if (direction != UNINITIALIZED) and (size == UNINITIALIZED):
        raise Exception('Use both parameters or none') 
    self.direction = direction
    self.size = size
```

What do you think would be the pythonic way of doing this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Size and direction sound like a tuple to me:

```
class myVector():    
    def __init__(self, sd=(UNINITIALIZED, UNINITIALIZED)):
       try:
           self.size, self.direction = sd
       except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
           raise ValueError('two values of size and direction must be specified')
```

It is then called with a tuple of both size and direction if the defaults aren't wanted.

If you didn't want to change the semantics to require passing a tuple, an alternative if you're not using other arguments is to change sd to `*args` and do the same thing - that seems less explicit to me though and means you can't use optional args for anything else.

Comment: Thanks! A little change in the design that makes sense.

Comment: If you use the *args semantic, it is not possible to assign default values. I dealt with this case below.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the class like this:

```
class myVector():
    def __init__(self,*direction_and_size):
        if not len(direction_and_size):
            direction_and_size = [UNINITIALIZED, UNINITIALIZED]
        assert len(direction_and_size) == 2, "Please provide both parameters"
        self.direction,  self.size = direction_and_size

>>> v = myVector()
>>> v = myVector(4,2)
>>> v = myVector(4)
AssertionError: Please provide both parameters
```

Comment: Thanks Frodon, Asserting the length of the number of inputs is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class myVector():
    def __init__(self, direction = -1, size = -1):
        if (-1 in (direction, size)):
            self.size, self.direction = (-1, -1) #do your own fault/error handling here
                                                 #this just makes the example easier
        else:
            self.size = size,
            self.direction = direction

c1 = myVector(1, 1)
c2 = myVector(1)
c3 = myVector()

print(c1.direction, c2.direction, c3.direction)
```

Outputs:
    1 -1 -1

Comment: Thanks Daan Timmer, I like the graceful degradation that simply sets both values to default in case of either of them being defualt.